# Getting Shutdown and restart notifications in macOS

Tags: c++, power-management, iokit, kernel-extension, xnu

I'd like my IOKit driver to get notification of `power off` and `restart` events. Fortunately, IOKit provides this sort of notification using `IOService::systemWillShutDown` method which should be overwritten and include my logic as well.

Here's an example from [Apple Technical Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/IOKitFundamentals/PowerMgmt/PowerMgmt.html):

```
void MyExampleDriver::systemWillShutdown( IOOptionBits specifier )
{ 
    if ( kIOMessageSystemWillPowerOff == specifier ) {
        // System is shutting down; perform appropriate processing.
    } else if ( kIOMessageSystemWillRestart == specifier ) {
        // System is restarting; perform appropriate processing.
    }
    /*
     * You must call your superclass's implementation of systemWillShutdown as
     * soon as you're finished processing your shutdown or restart
     * because the shutdown will not proceed until you do.
     */
    super::systemWillShutdown( specifier );
}
```

However, the event doesn't show as expected.

Perhaps missing the registration to power plane phase (although it's not stated clearly as prerequisite to overriding the method `systemWillShutDown` from `IOService`.)

```
PMinit();
provider->joinPMtree(this);
registerPowerDriver(this, myPowerStates, 3);
```

Does joining the PMTree is mandatory in order to get the power events of restart and power off ?

While trying to debug the issue, I've put breakpoint in method `IOService::systemWillShutdown` and upon shutdown it's indeed being called with the following backtrace many times :

```
frame #0: 0xffffff80134b1b04 kernel`IOService::systemWillShutdown(this=0xffffff801a0cf800, specifier=3758096976) at IOServicePM.cpp:7167 [opt]
frame #1: 0xffffff80135123f1 kernel`PMHaltWorker::work(me=<unavailable>) at IOPMrootDomain.cpp:8165 [opt]
frame #2: 0xffffff8013512178 kernel`PMHaltWorker::main(arg=<unavailable>, waitResult=<unavailable>) at IOPMrootDomain.cpp:8095 [opt]
```

So it seems that there are other kernel extensions that DO get this call, and they are listed in `gPMHaltArray` - but my kext probably isn't there ..

Answer (score 1):

I think that the **PMinit()** call is mandatory as reported in the documentation:

> To participate in power management so that you receive notifications of power events, ensure your driver is correctly attached into the power plane

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/IOKitFundamentals/PowerMgmt/PowerMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP0000020-TPXREF104

Comment: I wonder how you can do this from a user space in a launch daemon?